# jquery notification will not show properly after form submit

Tags: php, ajax, validation, jquery

whats wrong with my code..

i want when i click on submit after filling whole form then the jquery notification will show,

the problem was that it shows the javascript alert box if field is not validated and submit the form with blank values either the form is completed or not.....

and when the form is filled properly it sends the blank value in email

Kindly review my code :

```
     <html>
<head>
<title>Form Validation</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.notifyBar.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.notifyBar.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function () {

$.post("formsubmit.php", $("#myForm").serialize(),  function(response) {   

{

   if( document.myForm.Name.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your name!" );
     document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
    if(myForm.Name.value.match(alphaExp)){

    }else{
        alert( "Name Should be in Alphabet!" );
        myForm.Name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if( document.myForm.Country.value == "-1" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your country!" );
     return false;
   }

   if( document.myForm.EMail.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
     document.myForm.EMail.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
    if(myForm.EMail.value.match(emailExp)){
    }else{
        alert( "Email ID appears to be Invalid" );
        myForm.EMail.focus();
        return false;
    }
   if( document.myForm.Phone.value == "" ||
           isNaN( document.myForm.Phone.value ) ||
           document.myForm.Phone.value.length != 10 )
   {
     alert( "Please provide a 10 Digit Mobile No." );
     document.myForm.Phone.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.myForm.quote.value == "-1" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your Quote!" );
     return false;
   }


}

$.notifyBar({ cssClass: "success", html: "Mail sent Successfully!" });
return false;
return true;


});


});

});




</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
 <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">
 <tr>
   <td align="right">Name</td>
   <td><input name="Name" type="text" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td align="right">Country </td>
   <td>
 <select name="Country" style="width:166px">
    <option value="-1">Choose..</option>
    <option>Afghanistan</option>
    <option>Albania</option>
    <option>Algeria</option>
    <option>American Samoa</option>
    <option>Andorra</option>
    <option>Angola</option>
    <option>Anguilla</option>
    <option>Antarctica</option>
    <option>Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option>Argentina</option>
    <option>Armenia</option>
    <option>Aruba</option>
    <option>Australia</option>
    <option>Austria</option>
    <option>Azerbaijan</option>
    <option>Bahamas</option>
    <option>Bahrain</option>
    <option>Bangladesh</option>
    <option>Barbados</option>
    <option>Belarus</option>
    <option>Belgium</option>
    <option>Belize</option>
    <option>Benin</option>
    <option>Bermuda</option>
    <option>Bhutan</option>
    <option>Bolivia</option>
    <option>Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option>Botswana</option>
    <option>Bouvet Island</option>
    <option>Brazil</option>
    <option>British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option>Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option>Bulgaria</option>
    <option>Burkina Faso</option>
    <option>Burundi</option>
    <option>Cambodia</option>
    <option>Cameroon</option>
    <option>Canada</option>
    <option>Cape Verde</option>
    <option>Cayman Islands</option>
    <option>Central African Republic</option>
    <option>Chad</option>
    <option>Chile</option>
    <option>China</option>
    <option>Christmas Island</option>
    <option>Cocos Islands</option>
    <option>Colombia</option>
    <option>Comoros</option>
    <option>Congo</option>
    <option>Congo, Democratic Republic of the</option>
    <option>Cook Islands</option>
    <option>Costa Rica</option>
    <option>Cote d'Ivoire</option>
    <option>Croatia</option>
    <option>Cuba</option>
    <option>Cyprus</option>
    <option>Czech Republic</option>
    <option>Denmark</option>
    <option>Djibouti</option>
    <option>Dominica</option>
    <option>Dominican Republic</option>
    <option>Ecuador</option>
    <option>Egypt</option>
    <option>El Salvador</option>
    <option>Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option>Eritrea</option>
    <option>Estonia</option>
    <option>Ethiopia</option>
    <option>Falkland Islands</option>
    <option>Faroe Islands</option>
    <option>Fiji</option>
    <option>Finland</option>
    <option>France</option>
    <option>French Guiana</option>
    <option>French Polynesia</option>
    <option>Gabon</option>
    <option>Gambia</option>
    <option>Georgia</option>
    <option>Germany</option>
    <option>Ghana</option>
    <option>Gibraltar</option>
    <option>Greece</option>
    <option>Greenland</option>
    <option>Grenada</option>
    <option>Guadeloupe</option>
    <option>Guam</option>
    <option>Guatemala</option>
    <option>Guinea</option>
    <option>Guinea-Bissau</option>
    <option>Guyana</option>
    <option>Haiti</option>
    <option>Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
    <option>Honduras</option>
    <option>Hong Kong</option>
    <option>Hungary</option>
    <option>Iceland</option>
    <option>India</option>
    <option>Indonesia</option>
    <option>Iran</option>
    <option>Iraq</option>
    <option>Ireland</option>
    <option>Israel</option>
    <option>Italy</option>
    <option>Jamaica</option>
    <option>Japan</option>
    <option>Jordan</option>
    <option>Kazakhstan</option>
    <option>Kenya</option>
    <option>Kiribati</option>
    <option>Kuwait</option>
    <option>Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option>Laos</option>
    <option>Latvia</option>
    <option>Lebanon</option>
    <option>Lesotho</option>
    <option>Liberia</option>
    <option>Libya</option>
    <option>Liechtenstein</option>
    <option>Lithuania</option>
    <option>Luxembourg</option>
    <option>Macao</option>
    <option>Madagascar</option>
    <option>Malawi</option>
    <option>Malaysia</option>
    <option>Maldives</option>
    <option>Mali</option>
    <option>Malta</option>
    <option>Marshall Islands</option>
    <option>Martinique</option>
    <option>Mauritania</option>
    <option>Mauritius</option>
    <option>Mayotte</option>
    <option>Mexico</option>
    <option>Micronesia</option>
    <option>Moldova</option>
    <option>Monaco</option>
    <option>Mongolia</option>
    <option>Montenegro</option>
    <option>Montserrat</option>
    <option>Morocco</option>
    <option>Mozambique</option>
    <option>Myanmar</option>
    <option>Namibia</option>
    <option>Nauru</option>
    <option>Nepal</option>
    <option>Netherlands</option>
    <option>Netherlands Antilles</option>
    <option>New Caledonia</option>
    <option>New Zealand</option>
    <option>Nicaragua</option>
    <option>Niger</option>
    <option>Nigeria</option>
    <option>Norfolk Island</option>
    <option>North Korea</option>
    <option>Norway</option>
    <option>Oman</option>
    <option>Pakistan</option>
    <option>Palau</option>
    <option>Palestinian Territory</option>
    <option>Panama</option>
    <option>Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option>Paraguay</option>
    <option>Peru</option>
    <option>Philippines</option>
    <option>Pitcairn</option>
    <option>Poland</option>
    <option>Portugal</option>
    <option>Puerto Rico</option>
    <option>Qatar</option>
    <option>Romania</option>
    <option>Russian Federation</option>
    <option>Rwanda</option>
    <option>Saint Helena</option>
    <option>Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
    <option>Saint Lucia</option>
    <option>Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option>Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
    <option>Samoa</option>
    <option>San Marino</option>
    <option>Sao Tome and Principe</option>
    <option>Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option>Senegal</option>
    <option>Serbia</option>
    <option>Seychelles</option>
    <option>Sierra Leone</option>
    <option>Singapore</option>
    <option>Slovakia</option>
    <option>Slovenia</option>
    <option>Solomon Islands</option>
    <option>Somalia</option>
    <option>South Africa</option>
    <option>South Georgia</option>
    <option>South Korea</option>
    <option>Spain</option>
    <option>Sri Lanka</option>
    <option>Sudan</option>
    <option>Suriname</option>
    <option>Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
    <option>Swaziland</option>
    <option>Sweden</option>
    <option>Switzerland</option>
    <option>Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option>Taiwan</option>
    <option>Tajikistan</option>
    <option>Tanzania</option>
    <option>Thailand</option>
    <option>The Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia</option>
    <option>Timor-Leste</option>
    <option>Togo</option>
    <option>Tokelau</option>
    <option>Tonga</option>
    <option>Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option>Tunisia</option>
    <option>Turkey</option>
    <option>Turkmenistan</option>
    <option>Tuvalu</option>
    <option>Uganda</option>
    <option>Ukraine</option>
    <option>United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option>United Kingdom</option>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
    <option>Uruguay</option>
    <option>Uzbekistan</option>
    <option>Vanuatu</option>
    <option>Vatican City</option>
    <option>Venezuela</option>
    <option>Vietnam</option>
    <option>Virgin Islands, British</option>
    <option>Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
    <option>Wallis and Futuna</option>
    <option>Western Sahara</option>
    <option>Yemen</option>
    <option>Zambia</option>
    <option>Zimbabwe</option>
</select></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td align="right">EMail</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="EMail" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td align="right">Phone</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Phone" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td align="right">Quote:</td>
   <td>
 <select name="quote" style="width: 166px; height:22px;">
                <option value="-1">Choose..</option>
                <option>BPO / Tech Support</option>
                <option>IT Consulting</option>
                <option>Website Designing</option>
                <option>Website Re-Designing</option>
                <option>PSD to HTML</option>
                <option>WebSite Development</option>
                <option>Software Development</option>
                <option>E-Commerce Development</option>
                <option>CMS Development</option>
                <option>Wordpress Development</option>
                <option>Joomla Development</option>
                <option>Logo Designing</option>
                <option>Domain Registration</option>
                <option>Web Hosting</option>
                <option>Server Solutions</option>
                <option>Gateway Integrations</option>
                <option>SEO / Web Promotions</option>
                <option>Social Media Optimization</option>
                <option>Mobile Applications</option>
                <option>Other</option>
            </select>
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td align="right">Comments:</td>
   <td><textarea cols="20" name="Comments" style="height: 43px"></textarea>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td align="right"></td>
   <td><input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You need to do the validation BEFORE calling `$.post()`. You're doing it in the callback that's executed when the server responds.

Comment: can u re-edit my code?

Comment: Done, although I thought my explanation was clear enough that you should be able to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit").click(function () {

    if( document.myForm.Name.value == "" )
    {
        alert( "Please provide your name!" );
        document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
        return false;
    }
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
    if(myForm.Name.value.match(alphaExp)){

    }else{
        alert( "Name Should be in Alphabet!" );
        myForm.Name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if( document.myForm.Country.value == "-1" )
    {
        alert( "Please provide your country!" );
        return false;
    }

    if( document.myForm.EMail.value == "" )
    {
        alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
        document.myForm.EMail.focus() ;
        return false;
    }
    var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
    if(!myForm.EMail.value.match(emailExp)){
        alert( "Email ID appears to be Invalid" );
        myForm.EMail.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if( document.myForm.Phone.value == "" ||
        isNaN( document.myForm.Phone.value ) ||
        document.myForm.Phone.value.length != 10 )
    {
        alert( "Please provide a 10 Digit Mobile No." );
        document.myForm.Phone.focus() ;
        return false;
    }
    if( document.myForm.quote.value == "-1" )
    {
        alert( "Please provide your Quote!" );
        return false;
    }

    $.post("formsubmit.php", $("#myForm").serialize(),  function(response) {
        $.notifyBar({ cssClass: "success", html: "Mail sent Successfully!" });
    });

    return false; // prevent default form submit

}
```

Comment: Barmar, By using this the javascript validation will not work not notification shows

Comment: Can you make a fiddle showing the problem? I think it should work like this.

Comment: I added a `return false` to the end, to prevent double submitting. But that shouldn't change the validation part.

Comment: its not showing, field validation, nor jquery notification, nor submit form nothing....its like dead form

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? There might be a syntax error, I just cut and pasted your code without any validation. Do you see errors in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Barmar's comment.

Instead of using the inappropriate *shorthand method* use the actual [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and hand that validation function as `beforeSend`.

Or you can call the $.post(...) from the end of your (anonymous) validation function (`function(response) {...}`). You should then of course call that validation function on click. (Edit: That would match Barmar's actual answer, I got ninja'd)